# Can't Install OpenJDK6

Tags: installation, openjdk

Well it started downloading packages but in between due to connection failure it stoped and now when I again run the same command I got this error:

```
Err http//in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main openjdk-6-jre-headless i386 6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.179 80]
Err http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main openjdk-6-jre-headless i386 6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main openjdk-6-jre i386 6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Err http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main openjdk-6-jdk i386 6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre_6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jdk_6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.10.2_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to switch to a different server/mirror, because the files are no longer on that particular server. (404 Not Found is pretty reliable).

I suppose there could be something else going on, though. You could try:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```

to clean the cache (and partially downloaded files) and then update your package lists.

Comment: Ohh thanx buddy its working...now :-)